# Compiling Scala source in a string at runtime

Tags: scala, reflection, runtime

I have an abstract class in my program as such

```
abstract class Deployment {

  /**
   * Defines a logger to be used by the deployment script
   */
  protected val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

  /**
   * Defines the entry point to the deployment
   *
   * @throws java.lang.Exception Thrown on the event of an unrecoverable error
   */
  def run(): Unit
}
```

And when I try loading classes they are in their source form so I compile them on load like so

```
val scriptFile = new File("testing.scala")

val mirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val toolBox = mirror.mkToolBox()

val parsedScript = toolBox.parse(Source.fromURI(scriptFile.toURI).mkString)
val compiledScript = toolBox.eval(parsedScript)

val deployment = compiledScript.asInstanceOf[Deployment]
deployment.run()
```

And this is the test file

```
import au.com.cleanstream.kumo.deploy.Deployment

class testing extends Deployment {

  override def run(): Unit = {
    logger.info("TEST")
  }

}
```

But when I run the code I get `java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed`, I have also tired `toolBox.compile(parsedScript)` but got the same thing.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toolBox.eval(parsedScript)` returns `() => Any`
In Your case the test file returns `Unit` and `compiledScript` is of type `BoxedUnit`.

If you change the test file to return some value, you will be able to access it.
I have modified test file as follows:

```
object Testing extends Deployment {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    logger.info("TEST")
  }
}
Testing //This is the SOLUTION
```

Comment: Thank you so much, looking back on this it makes much more sense!

Comment: Yes, much more sense! and I would like to add that it's possible to use anonymous object here, 
```new Deployment {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    logger.info("TEST")
  }
}
// end```